# Using the node 'url' module in Next.js react SSR app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I was in the process of looking for a url builder/parser module for my Next.js React app when I saw that the [next-routes](https://github.com/fridays/next-routes) module just imports the node 'url' module.

How is this handled through the browser lifecycle? Can I safely use `import url from 'url'` in my react code? Because next.js is isomorphic I am unsure as to how this gets handled/used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next.js use Webpack to bundle NPM modules to client as much as it possibly can.

As for core Node.js modules like `url`, Webpack internally has [node-libs-browser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libs-browser) module to export browser/mock implementation to client.

So yes, you can safely use `import url from 'url'` in React.

See also isomorphic module like [isomorphic-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isomorphic-fetch) that complement browser functionalities on server or vice versa.